# List<Map> to Object[]

Tags: java, list, object, casting

I have this cast

```
List<Map> headers = (List<Map>) responseMap.get("headers");
```

and it works but I'd like to cast it to Object[] so I tried

```
Object[] rows = (Object[]) responseMap.get("data");
```

but I got

```
java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to [Ljava.lang.Object;
```

how can I cast

```
List<Map> to Object[]?
```

Using Windows and JDK1.6

Comment: _Cast_ has a specific meaning: if an object is declared as A but really is B, you can cast it to B. But this means B extends A (B is-a A). No array is a list, no list is an array (which explains [sᴜʀᴇsʜ ᴀᴛᴛᴀ's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31585229/1734119)). What you mean is to _convert_, meaning you need to perform some calculation or processing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot. However, the `List` interface offers the `toArray()` method. So:

```
Object[] rows = responseMap.get("data").toArray();
```

Answer (score 2):

You can transform a `List<Object>` to `Object[]` like following.

```
List<Object> list = //List of Objects
Object[] array = list.toArray(new Object[0]);
```

Or you can use a non generic method [`toArray()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#toArray()) like following

```
Object[] array = ((List<Map>)responseMap.get("data")).toArray();
```

Comment: You should point out that ths isn't casting `List<Object>` to `Object[]`.

Comment: @ReyCharles : Yes, Done!